# Problem drawing diagram with XY-Pic

Tags: diagrams

How I can draw the following diagram with  XY-Pic :

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you explicitly need to do it with XY-Pic or may be the package `tikz-cd` may fit your needs? By the way, could you show what is your real problem? What is your actual code? What did you try so far?

Comment: @Manuel, I want to do with Pic-xy, because I'm not familiar with tikz-cd.

Comment: As you see in Gonzalo's answer, it's quite easy to learn ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the powerful and more modern [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package is an option (the syntax is similar to that of `xy`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
Z\ar[dashed]{rr}\ar{drrr}\ar{dr} & & X\times_{S} Y\ar{dl}\ar{dr} \\
& X\ar{dr} & & Y\ar{dl} \\
& & S
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is simple

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

    \[
    \xymatrix{
    Z\ar[rd]\ar[rrrd]\ar@{-->}[rr] &   & X\times_S Y\ar[ld]\ar[rd] & \\
      & X\ar[rd] &             & Y\ar[ld]\\
      &   &     S       &
    }
    \]

\end{document}
```